# USDZ export from SceneKit results in dull models

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, usdz

I am trying to use the new iOS13 ability to export a usdz file from a SCNScene using the
 `func write(to url: URL, options: [String : Any]? = nil, delegate: SCNSceneExportDelegate?, progressHandler: SCNSceneExportProgressHandler? = nil) -> Bool` 
function of SCNScene.

If I use a baked in .scn file with no modifications, it works great but I run into all sorts of problems when I try to insert in my own texture.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "scene.scnassets/original.scn")!
let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Plane", recursively: true)
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
node?.geometry = plane
node?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
node?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.contents = NSNumber(value: 0.0) //or UIColor.black doesn't work either

let documentsUrl = self.fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
guard !documentsUrl.isEmpty,
let url = documentsUrl.first else {
    completion(nil)
    return
}
let finalUrl = url.appendingPathComponent("result.usdz")
_ = scene.write(to: finalUrl, delegate: nil)
```

original.scn just has a glossy plane and I've tried to again set the roughness to 0 when I change the material. The resulting usdz always has the roughness set to 0.9 though. Has anyone else experienced this and found a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default lighting model is `SCNLightingModelBlinn` which means the material used for the `plane` geometry is not physically based. USDZ only supports physically based materials and upon export SceneKit will try to build a PBR material from the Blinn material, and will infer a `roughness` on your behalf.

The fix consists in setting `lightingModelName` to `SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased`.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I just needed to add the following line
`node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased`